# Ionic offline authentication

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework in order to build a hybrid mobile application.
The app requires user authentication, without being connected to the internet.
The users' usernames and pwd are already stored in the database, they will not be asked to sign up.
I googled this many times and I found a tool called PouchDB, but it needs server side :(.
Do you  have an idea o  how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store the username + password table on LocalStorage.  [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) might be what you're looking for.

You would also need to have an implementation of your authentication logic on client side.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend storing usernames/password in local storage.

An idea for authentication in offline is to store an auth token in local storage (ngStorage) if the user has already logged in prior to being offline.

No need to validate the information but rather check for the presence. When the phone comes back online you could do a check against the server to make sure it's still valid then handle as neccesary.

Comment: I won't use a server.
the app is not connected to the internet.

Comment: I'm curious now if it doesn't connect to internet why does it need authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PouchDB offline, it only needs server side if you want to sync its contents to another PouchDB/CouchDB instance on a server. Store you user and password to PouchDB, create a login form and check user validation on login.

Comment: Thanks, the project i was working on ended in spetember :D
I used SQLite.